# How to insert multiple rows for a unique ID

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, rows

I'm trying to achieve this insert as a result in DB:

```
USER ID    SERVICE  OPERATION

2681    6        47
2681    6        48
2681    6        95
2681    6        104
2681    12       106
2681    12       116
```

for 3000 unique user id's where second and third column data are the same for every user id.

I could do

```
INSERT INTO table (user, service, operation)
   VALUES ('2681', '6', '47'); ('2681', '6', '48'); etc..
```

and repeat this for 18000 rows.

Is there a more simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could shorten the code using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` and a collection:

```
INSERT INTO table_name ( user, service, operation )
SELECT '2681', '6', op.COLUMN_VALUE
FROM   TABLE( SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST( 47, 48, 95, 104 ) ) op;
```

If you wanted you can cross join multiple collections:

```
INSERT INTO table_name ( user, service, operation )
SELECT usr.COLUMN_VALUE,
       srv.COLUMN_VALUE,
       op.COLUMN_VALUE
FROM   TABLE( SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST( '2681', '2682' ) ) usr,
       TABLE( SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST( '6', '12' ) ) srv,
       TABLE( SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST( 47, 48, 95, 104 ) ) op;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use an insert select:

```
insert into my table (user, service, operation) 
with sop(service, operation) as
(
  select  6,  47 from dual union all
  select  6,  48 from dual union all
  select  6,  95 from dual union all
  select  6, 104 from dual union all
  select 12, 106 from dual union all
  select 12, 116 from dual
)
select users.user, sop.service, sop.operation
from sop
cross join users;
```